# Не могу описать метод добавления в список

Tags: c#, консоль, .net-core

Есть код, в котором мне необходимо реализовать работу интерфейса,

```
public interface IUsersStorage
    {
        List<User> GetAll();

        User TryGetById(int id);
        void Add(User user);
    }
```

и вот что должно получаться при выводе на консоль

```cs
 IUsersStorage usersStorage = new UsersInMemoryStorage();
 List<User> users = usersStorage.GetAll();

 usersStorage.Add(new User { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan", Age = 25 });
 usersStorage.Add(new User { Id = 2, Name = "NeIvan", Age = 2 });
 Console.WriteLine(users.Count == 2); // True
```

Так как мне реализовать метод Add, чтобы все работало?
Я, честно признаюсь, третий день пытаюсь решить это.
С условием что в Main() ничего менять нельзя.

Класс UsersInMemoryStorage

```
public class UsersInMemoryStorage : IUsersStorage
    {
        private static List<User> _users = new List<User>();

        public void Add(User user)
        {
            
        }

        public List<User> GetAll()
        {
            List<User> vs = new List<User>();
            foreach (User item in _users)
            {
                vs.Add(item);
            }
            return vs;
        }

        public User TryGetById(int id)
        {
            foreach (var item in _users)
            {
                if (item.Id == id)
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А класс `UsersInMemoryStorage` у вас есть? Или его нужно реализовать?

Comment: Есть, в нем реализованы остальные методы интерфейса, все кроме Add, с его реализацией как раз таки проблема

Comment: Добавьте код этого класса.

Comment: Добавил код класса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку по условию должен измениться уже возвращённый список - вам нельзя делать копию списка, вы должны вернуть внутренний список или обёртку над ним.

Поскольку вы возвращаете именно `List<User>`, а не какой-нибудь интерфейс - вы не можете возвращать обёртку.

Таким образом, для решения задачи нужно написать вот так:

```cs
public List<User> GetAll()
{
    return _users;
}
```

---

А теперь важное замечание: **никогда так не делайте**. Вам **нужно** поменять Main.

Или откажитесь от требования мутации уже возвращённого списка:

```cs
 IUsersStorage usersStorage = new UsersInMemoryStorage();
 List<User> usersBefore = usersStorage.GetAll();

 usersStorage.Add(new User { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan", Age = 25 });
 usersStorage.Add(new User { Id = 2, Name = "NeIvan", Age = 2 });
 List<User> usersAfter = usersStorage.GetAll();

 Console.WriteLine($"before {usersBefore.Count}, after {usersAfter.Count}"); // before 0, after 2
```

Или же используйте read-only интерфейсы:

```cs
public interface IUsersStorage
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<User> GetAll();

    User TryGetById(int id);
    void Add(User user);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, изменение метода GetAll помогло. По условию задачи я не могу менять Main, так как это задача на степике.

Answer (score -1):

```html
//Создаем хранилище.
 IUsersStorage usersStorage = new UsersInMemoryStorage();
                
//Добавляем в хранилище юзеров

 usersStorage.Add(new User { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan", Age = 25 });
 usersStorage.Add(new User { Id = 2, Name = "NeIvan", Age = 2 });
//Затем берем всех юзеров.
 List<User> users = usersStorage.GetAll();
 Console.WriteLine(users.Count == 2); // True
```

Проблема в том что в Main ошибка List users = usersStorage.GetAll();
Юзеры берутся раньше чем добавляются, так что всегда будет False

```html
            public void Add(User user)
            {
                _users.Add(user);

            }
```

Comment: да, должно быть true

Comment: Увы, но условия в Main никак нельзя менять, от меня требуют реализовать метод Add чтобы в Main все работало не изменяя там же ничего